# problems occurring with fgets when a program is executed from command prompt

Tags: c

```
scanf("%d",&a);

fflush(stdin);

fgets(ch,SIZE,stdin);    //SIZE=100 and ch is a char array
```

i have just used only this portion of code.It works fine normally.But when i am executing this programm from cmnd prmpt by using `file.exe < input.txt > output.txt` it's giving a garbage value in output.txt file.

Comment: Please show an example of input.txt and what you expect to be in output.txt and write the whole code

Comment: The behaviour of `fflush(stdin)` is not defined in the standard.

Comment: `scanf` and `fgets` don't mix well, because they work differently; the former reads words, the latter lines. Perhaps you should use `scanf("%d ", &a)` - note the space after `%d` and omit the `fflush`. (Or use `fgets` throughout and use ´sscanf` on the read line when you need to parse it.)

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is bad mkay. `fflush` is meant to be used on _output_ streams, not input streams. Just add a space-char to your `scanf` call, or use an alternative, since `scanf` can cause buffer overrun

Comment: The code does not output _anything_.  What did you expect to be in output.txt?

Answer (score 1):

You can flush `stdin` using `getchar` or `fgetc(stdin)`:

```
static void flush_stdin(void)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}

scanf("%d",&a);
flush_stdin();
fgets(ch,SIZE,stdin);    //SIZE=100 and ch is a char array
```