# Infinite loop in C when entered character

Tags: c

I am writing an objective c program for hangman. I need to replicate another program which has been given to me. I have done most of it, but am having an issue. It has to replicate the other program exactly, so I went into the other one and entered a character into the wordlength. It came up with the "number must be between 3 and 14 (inclusive)" statement, and asked me to enter a number again, but it started to loop infinitely. It works when i enter a number lower than 3 and larger than 14 (comes up with the error and asks for another input) but with a letter it infinitely loops. Also, the loop is meant to loop infinitely until the word length is larger than 3 and less than 14. That is why the while loop will loop infinitelyAny ideas??? Thanks

```
while (i == 0) {
    printf("\n\n > Please enter a word length: ");
    scanf("%i", &wordLength);
    printf("\n\n");

    if (wordLength > 3 && wordLength < 14) {
        continue;
    }
    else printf("number must be between 3 and 14 (inclusive)");
}
```

Comment: Why do you post the [same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656132/skipping-over-scanf-statement-in-c/22656386#22656386), with a difference of 20 minutes? if you want to apport new information or improve your question edit the question, but no duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem (that you seem to be asking about) here is that you don't check for errors from the [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) call. It will return with the number of successfully scanned items, or zero if none were scanned, or `EOF` on error.

If `scanf` fails to extract data from the input, like when you ask for an integer but the user write a letter, then that letter will continue to be in the input buffer, so the next call to `scanf` will see that letter again. And again and again...

The best way to fix this is to read the whole line, as text, into a buffer, and then try to parse the integer from this buffer (using e.g. `sscanf`):

```
char input[16];
if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error reading your input\n");
    exit(0);  /* Do whatever error handling you want */
}

if (sscanf(input, "%d", &wordLength) != 1)
{
    printf("Error: Input was not a valid integer\nPlease try again: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I fix this?

Comment: @user3283315 , use `fgetc(stdin)` or `getchar()` after `scanf` to [flush stdin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22463391/1606345)

Comment: @AlterMann There are better ways of handling this, as there is no way of knowing how many non-digit characters may be in the input.

Comment: @user3283315 Updated answer with some code

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, no matter how many non digits, `while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);` will flush all, but yes, `fgets` and `sscanf` is a much better option

Comment: You forget the variable in `sscanf`, edited and +1, thats the right answer for me

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with `while (i == 0){` you never change `i` in the loop. You may want to update it to

```
 while (wordLength == 0){
```

But make sure you do `wordLength=0` before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

change the value of `i` for the loop to terminate. you dint change the value of `i` anywhere inside loop.

```
continue;
```

will not exit the loop, it will just skip the statement after `continue` statement and start the loop again. To exit the loop use

```
break;
```

so use `break` or change the value of `i` to some value other than `i=0` to exit the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant `break` instead of `continue`:

```
if (wordLength > 3 && wordLength < 14)
    break;
```

`break` will take you out of the loop, whereas `continue` skips to the next iteration of the loop (which , as others have mentioned, never terminates because `i` is never changed)

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to break your loop when the condition is met.

```
while ( 1 ){

    printf("\n\n > Please enter a word length: ");
    scanf("%i", &wordLength);
    printf("\n\n");
    if (wordLength > 3 && wordLength < 14) {
        break;
    } 
    else printf("number must be between 3 and 14 (inclusive)");
}
```